# Django REST string escaping

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a REST API developed using Django Rest Framework. I am wondering if I have to do string escaping of the data coming from a POST request (before it's stored in the database) or does DRF already do that for me? 
I know that Django does some autoescaping, but not sure if it's the case for DRF as well.

Comment: I did a small test - sent a request with a string with html tags, i.e. '<b>Foo</b>'. Nothing happened to this string and it was saved 'as is'. My question then is - how do I avoid XSS attacks? Do I need to worry about saving unescaped strings to a DB and/or before rendering in Django?  I see some utility functions in Django like escape or strip_tags, but I can't find information on if and when to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping user input *is* one good defense against XSS attacks. Typically it's done at the point of rendering, not at the point where the data is exposed. For example, in Django server side templates, it's done in the templates, not in the ORM. This allows developers to choose how to render data based on their needs (e.g. some data may be markdown).

Looking at a few client side frameworks, they all escape output by default, and force developers to explicitly declare when they want to render raw html:

- React: [SetDangerouslyHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
- Angular 2: [[innerHTML]](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xss)
- Vue: [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

I'd recommend not trying to force this into the API but into the consumers of the API.